# Hibernate: table gets empty after trying to list it

Tags: java, hibernate

I have this lines to save an employee to a table. The code works ok.

```
    Employee e1=new Employee();
    e1.setId(115);
    e1.setFirstName("sonoo");
    e1.setLastName("jaiswal");
    session.persist(e1);//persisting the object
    t.commit();//transaction is commited
```

The problem: if I replace those lines by others to list the employees inside the table I get no results, besides, the tables gets empty, so the employee's data just inserted is not inside the table O_o

Any help?

Here you have the full snippet:

```
        Configuration cfg=new Configuration();
        cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");//populates the data of the configuration file

        //creating seession factory object
        SessionFactory factory=cfg.buildSessionFactory();

        //creating session object
        Session session=factory.openSession();

        //creating transaction object
        Transaction t=session.beginTransaction();
/*
        Employee e1=new Employee();
        e1.setId(115);
        e1.setFirstName("sonoo");
        e1.setLastName("jaiswal");
        session.persist(e1);//persisting the object
        t.commit();//transaction is commited
    */

        List result = session.createQuery( "from Employee" ).list();
        //Query query = session.createQuery("from Employee");
        for ( Employee employee : (List<Employee>) result ) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, employee.getFirstName()); //<- THIS IS NOT BEING CALLED
            //System.out.println( "Employee (" + employee.getFirstName());
        }

        session.close();

        System.out.println("successfully saved");
```

Comment: Can you please provide your hibernate.cfg.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet that you have `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop` in your `hibernate.cfg.xml` so when you relaunch your application, DB simply gets dropped and created from the scratch. Try to persist,commit, open new transaction (or not) and list again - I bet there will be persisted `Employee`. Remote it from config file or change to `validate`.